# Assign Object Type to Action Return?

Tags: c#, action

If you have the following method, where the result of calling the Action parameter will return the type of the passed in generic T1, how would you write it? I keep running into compiler errors.

```
private static void Test<T1>(T1 report, Action action)
{
    report = action;

}
```

Comment: Even aside from the compile-time errors, why have a parameter if you're then going to immediately ignore it?

Comment: Just a poor example on my part.

Comment: Here's a hint: be careful what you ask for - the answers may follow your poor example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Action return type is `void` i.e. it doesn't return anything.

You need to use `Func<T1>` instead like this -

```
private static void Test<T1>(T1 report, Func<T1> action)
{
    report = action.Invoke();
}
```

OR

```
private static void Test<T1>(T1 report, Func<T1> action)
{
    report = action();
}
```

Comment: Why not just `report = action();`?

Comment: Yeah its same. Thanks.

Comment: Why does action.Invoke() even exist? Horrible syntax.

Comment: Note that the method's parameter is currently pointless, as is the assignment to it....